# Websocket error "Upgrade required" when trying to access deployed version of the app

Tags: go, websocket

I have a simple ws server, here's the code:

```
package ws

import (
    "github.com/gofiber/contrib/websocket"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func UseWebsocket(app *fiber.App) {
    app.Use("/ws", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
            c.Locals("allowed", true)
            return c.Next()
        }
        return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
    })

    app.Get("/ws/comments", websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {
        // some logic here
    }))
}
```

main.go

```
func main() {
    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{})

    ws.UseWebsocket(app)

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, world!")
    })

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    app.Listen(":" + port)
}
```

Locally it works totally fine, I can connect to it and get messages no problem.

But when I try to access it from my server after deployment, I get 426 Upgrade Required error (most likely from the `if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {`, honestly I am not sure about purpose of this middleware, I just copied it from the docs).

I've got an SSL certificate for my domain, and I tried both ws://api.myserver.com/ws and wss://api.myserver.com/ws, the error is the same. Have no idea how to debug this and what I could've missed here.

I assume the problem may be on the nginx configuration side. Do I need to do anything else here to make websocket work?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 60M;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://rest-api:9000;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its nginx releated, Just Google nginx websocket Reverse Proxy. I think U need Upgrade stuff in there